# Run Map/Reduce on non-parallelized problems?

Tags: mapreduce

I've been doing a lot of reading about Map Reduce and I had the following question that I can't seem to find the answers to:

- can you run Map/Reduce on non-parallelized problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course.  There are a lot of applications which can run something using map-reduce framework. For example `Qubole`. If you submit simple shell command like `"java -version"`, `Qubole` starts map-reduce job and run your command on mapper. check it yourself. **In this case map-reduce framework bothering about resource management, task coordinating, retrying, logging, monitoring status etc.**

The same if you try to execute `sqoop import` with --m1 parameter, it will query source database and load data into hdfs using single mapper without splitting. In this case MapReduce will not help to parallelize but it will decide where to run it, will retry, log, etc, you are able to kill job using same hadoop job or yarn commands.